# Include vars from a file for multiple import_playbooks

Tags: ansible, yaml

This is an error using Ansible 2.7

I am trying to include a files with vars in it into my playbook that has multiple import_playbooks.

I have 3 files.

1. one with all the vars
2. one with a playbook and a task
3. one with an import_playbook

My playbook:

```
---
- name: Create CPG
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
   - name: Create CPG "{{ cpg_name }}"
     hpe3par_cpg:
      storage_system_ip: "{{ storage_system_ip }}"
      storage_system_username: "{{ storage_system_username }}"
      storage_system_password: "{{ storage_system_password }}"
      state: present
      cpg_name: "{{ cpg_name }}"
      #domain: "{{ domain }}"
      growth_increment: "{{ growth_increment }}"
      growth_increment_unit: "{{ growth_increment_unit }}"
      growth_limit: "{{ growth_limit }}"
      growth_limit_unit: "{{ growth_limit_unit }}"
      growth_warning: "{{ growth_warning }}"
      growth_warning_unit: "{{ growth_warning_unit }}"
      raid_type: "{{ raid_type }}"
      set_size: "{{ set_size }}"
      high_availability: "{{ high_availability }}"
      disk_type: "{{ disk_type }}"
```

The playbook where I will call my tasks and my variables:

```
---
- name: master
  hosts: localhost

- import_playbook: create_CPG.yml
   include_vars: properties/variables.yml
```

I get this error when running "ansible-playbook create_master.yml"

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  mapping values are not allowed in this context

The error appears to have been in '/home/simon/Documents/Ansible/create_MasterPlaybook.yml': line 6, column 16, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- import_playbook: create_CPG.yml
   include_vars: properties/variables.yml
               ^ here
```

Is there a way to call a file with variables for only this import_playbook.

thank you

Comment: this seems a syntax error the indentation is giving error

Comment: tried a lot of different things, always same error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sup>(Update 14 Jun 2022 for Ansible 2.12)</sup>

Q: *"**Is there a way to call a file with variables for only this import_playbook?**"*

A: No. It is not. The variables included in a task are visible in the whole playbook to the affected hosts. [include_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html#include-vars-load-variables-from-files-dynamically-within-a-task) is a task.  The correct syntax would be

```yaml
- name: master
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_vars: properties/variables.yml

- import_playbook: create_CPG.yml
```

[import_playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_playbook_module.html#import-playbook-import-a-playbook) is not a tasks. It is a module that *"Includes a file with a list of plays to be executed"*. You can declare *vars* in the scope of the imported plays. For example,

```yaml
- import_playbook: create_CPG.yml
  vars:
    var1: value of var1
```

But, you can't declare *vars_files* at the moment. The import below

```yaml
- import_playbook: create_CPG.yml
  vars_files:
    - properties/variables.yml
```

will fail with the error:

> ERROR! 'vars_files' is not a valid attribute for a PlaybookInclude

See Ansible issue [Support vars_files when using import_playbook #36806](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/36806). This will solve your problem when implemented.

---

**Workaround**

Put the name of the file into a variable and use *vars*. For example, given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
host1 var1=1
host2 var1=2
```

, the file with the play

```yaml
shell> cat pb-import.yml
- hosts: host1,host2
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - "{{ my_vars_file|default('vars_file_default.yml') }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          var1: {{ var1|d('undef') }}
          var2: {{ var2|d('undef') }}
```

, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- import_playbook: pb-import.yml

- import_playbook: pb-import.yml
  vars:
    my_vars_file: vars_file_play_A.yml

- import_playbook: pb-import.yml
  vars:
    my_vars_file: vars_file_play_B.yml
```

, and the files with the variables for various playbooks

```yaml
shell> cat vars_file_default.yml
var2: play default
```

```yaml
shell> cat vars_file_play_A.yml
var2: play A
```

```yaml
shell> cat vars_file_play_B.yml
var2: play B
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [host1,host2] ***************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: |-
    var1: 1
    var2: play default
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: |-
    var1: 2
    var2: play default

PLAY [host1,host2] ***************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: |-
    var1: 1
    var2: play A
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: |-
    var1: 2
    var2: play A

PLAY [host1,host2] ***************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: |-
    var1: 1
    var2: play B
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: |-
    var1: 2
    var2: play B

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host1: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

**Scope of the variables**

The scope of the variables is more complex. See [Scoping variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#scoping-variables). There are three main scopes: global, play, and host. For example, given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
host1 var1=1
host2 var1=2
host3 var1=3
```

, the file

```yaml
shell> cat my_vars.yml 
var4: included in a task
```

, and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: host1,host2
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    var2: play
  tasks:
    - include_vars: my_vars.yml
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          var1: {{ var1|d('undef') }}
          var2: {{ var2|d('undef') }}
          var3: {{ var3|d('undef') }}
          var4: {{ var4|d('undef') }}

- hosts: host1,host2,host3
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          var1: {{ var1|d('undef') }}
          var2: {{ var2|d('undef') }}
          var3: {{ var3|d('undef') }}
          var4: {{ var4|d('undef') }}
```

gives the results below:

- Host scope. The variable *var1* declared in the inventory is available to the host in the whole playbook
- Play scope: The variable *var2* declared in the first play is available to all hosts in the first play only. The variable is undefined in the second play.
- Global scope. The variable *var3* declared as an extra variable at the command line is available globally to all hosts in all plays.
- The variable var4* declared in the *- include_vars: my_vars.yml* is available to the affected hosts only, i.e. hosts in the first play *host1,host2*. The variable is undefined to *host3*.

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e var3=global

PLAY [host1,host2] ***************************************************************************

TASK [include_vars] **************************************************************************
ok: [host1]
ok: [host2]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: |-
    var1: 1
    var2: play
    var3: global
    var4: included in a task
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: |-
    var1: 2
    var2: play
    var3: global
    var4: included in a task

PLAY [host1,host2,host3] *********************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: |-
    var1: 1
    var2: undef
    var3: global
    var4: included in a task
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: |-
    var1: 2
    var2: undef
    var3: global
    var4: included in a task
ok: [host3] => 
  msg: |-
    var1: 3
    var2: undef
    var3: global
    var4: undef

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host1: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host3: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

The results are the same if the playbooks are imported. For example, given the file

```yaml
shell> cat pb-import.yml
- hosts: host1,host2,host3
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          var1: {{ var1|d('undef') }}
          var2: {{ var2|d('undef') }}
          var3: {{ var3|d('undef') }}
          var4: {{ var4|d('undef') }}
```

and the imports added to the previous playbook

```yaml
- import_playbook: pb-import.yml
  vars:
    var2: play3

- import_playbook: pb-import.yml
```

give

```yaml
PLAY [host1,host2,host3] *********************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: |-
    var1: 1
    var2: play3
    var3: global
    var4: included in a task
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: |-
    var1: 2
    var2: play3
    var3: global
    var4: included in a task
ok: [host3] => 
  msg: |-
    var1: 3
    var2: play3
    var3: global
    var4: undef

PLAY [host1,host2,host3] *********************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: |-
    var1: 1
    var2: undef
    var3: global
    var4: included in a task
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: |-
    var1: 2
    var2: undef
    var3: global
    var4: included in a task
ok: [host3] => 
  msg: |-
    var1: 3
    var2: undef
    var3: global
    var4: undef
```

Comment: Why is it possible to do -import_playbook: XX and under; vars: xx: xx? This works

Comment: Because *vars:* is not a module. *include_vars* is a module.

Comment: erf. thanks for you answer. They should add this feature. it is quite important.

Comment: I updated the answer. [*vars_files*](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/36806) will solve the problem when implemented.

Comment: I added a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The import_playbook module doesn't accept - include_vars as an argument.

```
- import_playbook: create_CPG.yml
- include_vars: properties/variables.yml
```

For calling include_vars specific you can use the include_vars module inside that playbook

Answer (score 1):

this will be the ideal solution if you want to run import playbook with when condition. where `system_ip` can defined in `properties/variables.yml`

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  vars_files:
    - properties/variables.yml
  tasks:
    - set_fact: 
        storage_system_ip: "{{ system_ip }}"
  
- import_playbook: create_CPG.yml
  when: "storage_system_ip == '192.168.0.2' and ansible_architecture == 'x86_64'"
```