# Import_playbook with variables file

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I am working on a playbook wrapper for another playbook, therefore it seems I need to use directive `import_playbook`. Th problem is that I have a list of variables to add there and import_playbook seems to NOT accept `vars_files` directive. SO I tried `include`. Take a look:

```
---
- name: Prepare AWX installation on localhost
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  connection: local
  tasks:
  ...
  - name: Install docker-compose
    pip:
      name: docker-compose

  - name: Load AWX variables
    include_vars: config_vars.yml

  - name: launch TOWER installation
    include: /awx-repo/installer/install.yml
```

But ends wit error:
`ERROR! conflicting action statements: hosts, roles`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include vars from a file for multiple import\_playbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56023040/include-vars-from-a-file-for-multiple-import-playbooks)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to [include](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_module.html#include-include-a-play-or-task-list) a playbook among tasks. Quoting:

> *"Files with a list of plays can only be included at the top level."*

Fix the indentation. For example

```yaml
---
- name: Prepare AWX installation on localhost
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  connection: local
  tasks:
  ...
  - name: Install docker-compose
    pip:
      name: docker-compose

  - name: Load AWX variables
    include_vars: config_vars.yml

- name: launch TOWER installation
  include: /awx-repo/installer/install.yml
```

There will be this warning

> [DEPRECATION WARNING]: 'include' for playbook includes. You should use 'import_playbook'
> instead. This feature will be removed in version 2.12. Deprecation warnings can be disabled
> by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.

Use [import_playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_playbook_module.html#import-playbook-import-a-playbook). For example

```yaml
---
- name: Prepare AWX installation on localhost
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  connection: local
  tasks:
  ...
  - name: Install docker-compose
    pip:
      name: docker-compose

  - name: Load AWX variables
    include_vars: config_vars.yml

- name: launch TOWER installation
  import_playbook: /awx-repo/installer/install.yml
```

Comment: Mostly it works, but for running on localhost I have to specify variable `ansible_connection` in `import_playbook`, otherwise, despite it is in config_vars.yml, it will not work. I don't know why...